# Imaginary number to the power of imaginary number

Tags: complex-analysis

The value of i^i is e^(-π/2) ,that is 0.207879.
I'm doing an operation on imaginary number & answer is in real plane.
what is the graphical meaning of this?
Please explain this

Comment: The answer is (0.207879)+i(0).             its in real plane right?

Comment: The answer is, as mentioned, in the complex plane, however the value itself is real (which may be a surprise), being on the positive x-axis. When adding the multiples of 2*$\pi$i, then of course these values are complex

Comment: "The value of i^i is e^(-π/2)" Actually, no, the value of i^i is `undefined`.

Comment: @Ajay It's on the real *line*, which is part of the complex *plane*.

Comment: e^(i*π/2) means when we travel π/2 radians from point 1, that is from (1,0) in a unit circle ,we'll reach at i, that is (i, 0).that's why e^(i*π/2)=i. In this way How I can reach to 0.207879?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The answer is still in complex plane. $0.207$ is complex number. Suppose that $w=f(z)=i^z$ given. Then you map $z$'s to complex $w$-plane.

Let complex numbers $w, z$ is given. Then to calculate $z^w$ we write $$z^w = e^{w\times \ln z}$$ where $$\ln z = \ln \mid z\mid + i \arg(z)+ i2k\pi$$
Then you will simply multiply these complex numbers and calculate

$$e^{product}$$

Comment: Doing this to compute $z^w$ effectively *prevents* you to compute $z^w$ (except when $w$ is an integer).

Comment: Why? There is nothing wrong.

Comment: To begin with, because if one defines the logarithm as a set and uses this set to compute $z^w$, then $z^w$ can only be a set. But, just after you did exactly this, you explain that $z^w$ is a number... Set (of numbers) or (unique) number, please make up your mind! :-)